# An alternative way to solve permutations problem vs the common solution: does it work?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many different letter arrangements can be formed from the letters
>   $PEPPER$?

I understand the common way to solve a problem like this, that there are $$
\frac{n!}{{n_{1}!}{n_{2}!}\dots {n_{r}!}}
$$
different permutations of $n$ objects, where $n_{1},\dots {n_{n}}$ each are indistinguishable (i.e. $n_{1} = P$'s, $n_{2} = E$'s).

**I tried an alternative approach to this problem:**

I simplify the problem to  $$(\text{count possible places for } R)\cdot(\text{count of permutations of } PEPPE) \\ = 6 \cdot (\text{count of permutations of } PEPPE)$$

Let $x_{5}x_{4}x_{3}x_{2}x_{1}$ be some permutation of $PEPPE$.

For $x_{5}$ there are $(|P| + |E|) = (3 + 2)$ possible choices from $PEPPE$.

For $x_{4}$ there are $(|P - 1| + |E|) + (|P| + |E - 1|) = (2 + 2) + (3 + 1) = 8$ possible choices, since we can choose either $1\ P$ or $1\ E$.

For $x_{3}$, we continue to choose either $1\ P$ or $1\ E$, which gives me $$(|P - 2| + |E|) + ( |P - 1| + |E - 1|)+ (|P - 1| + |E - 1|) + (|P| + |E-2|)\\ = (1+2)+(2+1)+(2+1)+(3+0) = 12$$ possible choices.

Continuing for $x_{2},x_{1}$ we can see the count of choices would be the addition of $2$ times as many terms each time, which is too tedious for me to write here.

My reasoning is flawed somewhere; it's not leading to the correct answer: $60$. Can you please show me the flaws in my reasoning? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for concluding that there are $8$ choices for $x_4$. How can there be $8$ choices when there are only $4$ possible letters to place in that position (and only $2$ if you are considering that $P$ and $E$ are the same)?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I erroneously tried to express "For $x_4$, either $(P$ was chosen for $x_5)$ or $(E$ was chosen for $x_5)$ as "$(|P - 1| + |E|) + (|P| + |E - 1|) = (2 + 2) + (3 + 1) = 8$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I tried an alternative approach to this problem:**
>
> I simplify the problem to  $$(\text{count possible places for } R)\cdot(\text{count of permutations of } PEPPE) \\ = 6 \cdot (\text{count of permutations of } PEPPE)$$

This is a good beginning.  Why not just continue in the same manner?

$$(\text{count places for } R\text{ among the 6})\cdot(\text{count places for all }P\text{ among the remaining 5}) \\ = {^6{\rm C}_1} \cdot {^5{\rm C}_3} $$

$^6{\rm C}_1$ is of course, $6$.   There are $6$ ways to select $1$ place from $6$.

${^5{\rm C}_3}$ is $10$.   There are $5$ places for the first $P$, $4$ for the second, and $3$ for the last; *but* wait, which $P$ is which?    We must divide by the $3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ ways to arrange the $P$ among themselves.    So ${^5{\rm C}_3}$ is $(5\cdot 4\cdot 3)/(3\cdot 2\cdot 1)$.

There are $60$ distinct arrangements of the string "PEPPER"

$$\dfrac 61\cdot\dfrac {5!}{3!~2!} ~=~ \dfrac {6!}{1!~3!~2!}$$

---

Your method of counting neglects that the choices available to $x_4$ depend on what choices were made for $x_5$, and so on.   Further there are only $2$ choices available for $x_5$: either one from the identical $P$ or one from the identical $E$.   This continues untill either all two $E$ or all three $P$ have been used.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how I could have correctly reasoned the rest of the problem. But I disagree with the final comment that my reasoning  neglected that the choices available for $x_4$ depends upon what choices were made for $x_5$ and so on. Please see for $x_4$, where I erroneously tried to express "For $x_4$, either $(P$ was chosen for $x_5)$ or $(E$ was chosen for $x_5)$" as $(|P - 1| + |E|) + (|P| + |E - 1|) = (2 + 2) + (3 + 1) = 8$. While intended to be a literal translation, it is clearly incorrect to have $8$ ways to choose $1$ letter from $4$. What's the correct way to express this?

Answer (score 3):

another way(s) ...
Represent each arrangement as a 3-tuple...

- The first element being the set of three numbers representing the
  positions of the letter P
- The second element is the set of two    numbers representing the
  positions of the letter E
- The third element    is the number    representing the position of
  the letter R

So "PEPPER" would be represented by $(\{1, 3, 4\},\{2,5\},6) $

for each order of filling the 3 elements you can derive an expression for the answer   e.g. ...

"PER" $\to \binom 63 \binom 32\binom 11 = 60 $

"RPE" $\to \binom 61 \binom 53\binom 22 = 60 $

Answer (score 2):

You say

"For $x_5$ there are $(|P|+|E|)=(3+2)$ possible choices from PEPPE".

What does that mean? $x_5$ is either $P$ or E.

You have two possibilities: P**** or E****. In case 1, the
stars are an anagram of PPEE; how many of them are there.
Likewise in the other case, the stars are an anagram of PPPE.

Anyway the anagrams of PEPPE are PPPEE, PPEPE, PPEEP, PEPPE, PEPEP, PEEPP, EPPPE, EPPEP, EPEPP and EEPPP.